# ActiveMQ Artemis - Spring Boot Throttling

Tags: spring-boot, throttling, activemq-artemis

Set up - ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0 and Spring Boot.

Problem statement: I want to achieve throttling in terms of reading / limiting the messages to be read from ActiveMQ.

This can be achieved by configuring the [`consumerMaxRate`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html#rate-limited-flow-control) during the start time and that works fine too. I want to change this parameter on the fly to increase / decrease the rate of consumption without stopping my application. I have tried by re-initializing the beans, setting the activemqconnectionfactories again but somehow the connection is maintained with the initial value only.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

I have tried searching the documentation but it only says about the parameter but with no examples.

Comment: Artemis:  apache-artemis-2.14.0, boot: 2.3.1.RELEASE, I am using the "spring-boot-starter-artemis" to connect.

Comment: apologies it's `consumerMaxRate` as you pointed.

Comment: What's your use-case? Why do you need to vary the `consumerMaxRate`?

Comment: We need to send messages with respect to the server consuming from us, sometimes we will need to limit the numbers on need basis.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the use-case. You're basically just saying "we need to because we need to."

Answer (score 1):

The `consumerMaxRate` cannot be changed while the connection to the broker is active. You'd need to close the connection, set a new `consumerMaxRate`, and then create a connection with the new configuration.

Comment: So i am looking for changes on how to the close the connection and set up a new one without restarting ky app.

Comment: Well, that's really a different question for the Spring Boot folks. That has nothing to do with the broker or client.